# Length and sign of transposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, permutations

I have solved the following problem and I would like to know if my solution is correct and/or/how it could be improved, thanks.

Define a transposition as a permutation of the form $(1,2,\dots,i-1,j,\dots,j-1,i,\dots,n)$ where $1\leq i<j\leq n$, i.e. it interchanges $i$ and $j$ and leaves all other numbers fixed. Find the length and sign of a transposition and then also of permutation $(n,n-1,\dots,3,2,1).$

What I have done:

To bring $j$ to occupy $i$s place we have to switch $j-i$ times and then $i$, which is now in the $i+1$-st place, has to be switched another $j-(i+1)$ times to bring it to occupy what was $j$s place (now currently occupied by $j-1$.)
So, the length of the transposition is $l(\sigma)=j-1+j-(i+1)=2j-2i-1$ and its sign is thus $\text{sign}(\sigma)=(-1)^{2j-21-1}=(-1)^{2j-2i}(-1)^{-1}=\left((-1)^{2}\right)^{j-i}(-1)=1^{j-1}(-1)=-1$.

Using what we have just found we see that $(n,n-1,\dots,3,2,1)$ is the result of $\frac{n}{2}$ transpositions if $n$ is even and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ transpositions if $n$ is odd (the median element does not get transposed, since it doesn't have a distinct corresponding element) so $l(\sigma)=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2}&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\ \frac{n-1}{2}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$ thus $\text{sign}(\sigma)=\begin{cases}(-1)^\frac{n}{2}&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\ (-1)^\frac{n-1}{2}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}.$

Comment: Your answer looks reasonable.  Note you can combine even and odd using rounding down and $\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\big\rfloor$

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your interest in my question. I have a small doubt: in the notes I am self-learning from an inversion of a permutation $\sigma$ is defined as  "any pair of numbers $i$ and $j$ such that $1\leq i < j\leq n$ and
$\sigma(i) > \sigma( j)$. The length of $\sigma$, denoted by $l(\sigma)$, is the number of inversions of $\sigma$.[...] The sign of $\sigma$ is $\text{sign}(\sigma)=(-1)^{l(\sigma)}$." Then it lists the permutations of $(1,2,3)$ and among them there is the permutation $(3,2,1)$ which the author says has length $3$.

Comment: @Henry But shouldn't this permutation have length $1$ according to the definition given? I think the author meant, in the definition "any pair of ADJACENT numbers $i$ and $j$ such that $1\leq i < j\leq n$ and $\sigma(i) > \sigma( j)$" and I have used this modified definition in solving the problem above. Am I correct? Thanks